# How to define empty list in application.yml in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I've got application.yml in my spring boot project and want to declare empty list. I mean there is a two level config hierarchy. This class is required to get values declared in application.yml

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("book")
public class PropertiesReader {

    private List<Long> authors;

    public List<Long> getAuthors() {
        return new ArrayList<>(authors);
    }

    public void setAuthors(List<Long> authors) {
        this.authors= new ArrayList<>(authors);
    }
```

And this is how part of application.yml looks like

```
book:
   library: ${LIBRARY_REFERENCE:library}
   secondValue:
      expirationAfter: 10
   authors: ${AUTHORS_IDS:[]}
```

So values in curly brackets are declared in another, external configuration file. But if value isn't there declared, spring should assign default value that is declared after colon symbol. In single values it works, but in List if I declare it as above I'm getting NumberFormatException because value **[]** is assigned to list. How to write it properly?

In external configuration how should it be written also? If I want sometimes to declare values but sometimes it must be empty

```
name: AUTHORS_IDS
      value:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to put a colon sign. I have solved my problem like that, it works.

```
book:
   authors: ${AUTHORS_IDS:}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked in config declared inside project. But how to assign it on higher level, I've got exceptions like this: at <.value>: wrong type for value; expected string; But if i assign empty brackets for value, will it assign brackets to list instead of empty list? name: AUTHORS_IDS
      value: []

Comment: I'm glad my solution is working. You try empty value instead of empty brackets. Example: 

AUTHOR_IDS:

Comment: Neither an empty value nor a dash solves my problem :-(  I have an iterator that I want to make no iteration because it gets an empty list. Any Idea?